# Weird error messages, how to fix them?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

So I was just coding along, then Xcode just started going whack when I hit build and gave me all these error that I have never had before

Here is the file:

> ## import
>
> ```
> #import <OpenGLES/EAGLDrawable.h>
>
> #import "EAGLView.h"
>
> #define USE_DEPTH_BUFFER 0
>
> // A class extension to declare private methods @interface EAGLView ()
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) EAGLContext *context; @property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimer *animationTimer;
>
> - (BOOL) createFramebuffer;
> - (void) destroyFramebuffer;
> - (void) updateScene:(float)delta;
> - (void) renderScene;
>
> @end
>
>
> @implementation EAGLView
>
> @synthesize context; @synthesize animationTimer; @synthesize animationInterval;
>
>
> // You must implement this method
> + (Class)layerClass {
>     return [CAEAGLLayer class]; }
>
>
> //The GL view is stored in the nib file. When it's unarchived it's sent -initWithCoder:
> - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
>
>     if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
>         // Get the layer
>         CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
>
>         eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
>         eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>                                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
> ```
>
> kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];
>
> ```
>         context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];
>
>         if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
>             [self release];
>             return nil;
>         }
>
>         animationInterval = 1.0 / 60.0;
>               CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
>               // Set up OpenGL projection matrix      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);        glLoadIdentity();       glOrthof(0,
> ```
>
> rect.size.width, 0, rect.size.height, -1, 1);
>         glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);         glViewport(0, 0, rect.size.width,
>   rect.size.height);
>                     // Initialize OpenGL states         glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);      glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
>         glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_BLEND_SRC);
>         glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);       glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f,
>       0.0f, 1.0f);
>                     // init         [self initGame];
>
> ```
>         UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
>         accel.delegate = self;
>         accel.updateInterval = 1.0f / 60.0f;
>
>         //[sharedSoundManager playMusicWithKey:@"song" timesToRepeat:-1];
>     }
>     return self; }
>
> -(void) initGame{
>     //SET GAME STATE
>     //0 = Menu
>     //1 = Gameplay
>     //2 = death screen
>     gameState = 0;
>
>     player = [[Circle alloc] init];
>
>     score = 0;
>     scoreString = [NSString alloc];
>     scoreAdder = 1;
>     //[self setupScore];
>
>     menu = [[Image alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loadImage.png"]];
>     bk = [[Image alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bk.png"]];
>     squared = [[Image alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"squared.png"]];
>
>     gameRunning = TRUE;
>     gameState = 0;
>
>     squares = [[Squares alloc] init];
>     [squares addSquare: CGPointMake(100, 100) : 0];
>     //font = [[AngelCodeFont alloc]initWithFontImageNamed:@"font1.png" controlFile:@"font1.fnt"
> ```
>
> scale: 0.0f filter: nil];
>
> ```
>     // Init sound     sharedSoundManager = [SingletonSoundManager sharedSoundManager];    [sharedSoundManager loadSoundWithKey:@"menu"
> ```
>
> fileName:@"Menu" fileExt:@"mp3" frequency: 22050];
>           [sharedSoundManager loadBackgroundMusicWithKey:@"music" fileName:@"bkmusic" fileExt:@"aif"];
>
> ```
>     menuMusicVariable = 1;
>     gameMusicVariable = 1;
>      }
>
> -(void) setRunning: (bool) boolean{
>     gameRunning = boolean; }
>
> -(void) runContinueCountdown{
>     if(gameRunning == NO){
>
>         int timer = 300;
>         int countdownNum;
>         timer --;
>
>
>         if(timer <= 300){
>             if(timer > 200){
>                 countdownNum = 3;
>             }
>
>         if(timer <= 200){
>             if(timer > 100){
>                 countdownNum = 2;
>             }
>         }
>
>         if(timer <= 100){
>             if(timer >= 1){
>                 countdownNum = 1;
>             }
>         }
>
>         if(timer == 0 && countdownNum == 1){
>             [self setRunning: YES];
>         }
>     } }
>
>
> - (void) mainGameLoop {   CFTimeInterval      time;   float               delta;  time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();  delta = (time - lastTime);
> ```
>
> [self updateScene:delta];   [self renderScene];         lastTime = time;
>         }
>
> ```
> - (void)updateScene:(float)delta {    // Update Game Logic
>     if(gameRunning){
>         if(gameState == 0){
>
>             //MENU
>
>             if(menuMusicVariable == 1){
>                 [sharedSoundManager stopPlayingMusic];
>                 [sharedSoundManager playSoundWithKey:@"Menu" gain:10 pitch:10 location:Vector2fMake(0, 0) shouldLoop: TRUE];
>                 menuMusicVariable = 0;
>             }
>
>             [scoreLabel setHidden: YES];
>
>         } else if(gameState == 1){
>
>             //GAMEPLAY
>
>             if(gameMusicVariable == 1){
>                 [sharedSoundManager stopPlayingMusic];
>                 [sharedSoundManager playMusicWithKey: @"music" timesToRepeat: -1];
>                 gameMusicVariable = 0;
>             }
>
>             [scoreLabel setHidden: NO];
>
>             //game is running
>
>             if([player getAlive] == true){
>                 score = score + scoreAdder;
>             } else {
>                 score = score;
>             }
>
>             [player move];
>
>             [self checkSquareToCircleCollisions];
>             [self checkSquareToSquareCollisions];
>
>             [squares update];
>
>         } else if(gameState == 2){
>
>             //DEATH SCREEN
>
>             [sharedSoundManager stopPlayingMusic];
>
>             [scoreLabel setBounds: CGRectMake(100, 100 , 100, 40)];
>         }
>     } else {
>         //game is puased
>
>     } }
>
>
> - (void)renderScene {
>       // Make sure we are renderin to the frame buffer
>     [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
>     glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
>       // Clear the color buffer with the glClearColor which has been set  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);       //Render the game Scene 
>     if(gameState == 0){
>
>         //MENU
>         [menu renderAtPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0) centerOfImage: NO];
>
>     } else if(gameState == 1){
>
>         //GAMEPLAY
>
>         [bk renderAtPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0) centerOfImage: NO];
>
>         [self drawScore];
>
>         [player draw];
>
>         [squares render];
>         //[font drawStringAt: CGPointMake(150, 100) text:@"HELLO FONTS"];
>     } else if(gameState ==2){
>
>         //DEATH SCREEN
>
>         [squared renderAtPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0) centerOfImage: NO];
>
>     }         // Switch the render buffer and framebuffer so our scene is displayed on the screen
>     glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
>     [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES]; }
>
>
> - (void)layoutSubviews {
>     [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
>     [self destroyFramebuffer];
>     [self createFramebuffer];
>     [self renderScene]; }
>
>
> - (BOOL)createFramebuffer {
>
>     glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
>     glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
>
>     glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
>     glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
>     [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
>     glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
>
>     glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
>     glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);
>
>     if (USE_DEPTH_BUFFER) {
>         glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
>         glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
>         glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
>         glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
>     }
>
>     if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
>         NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
>         return NO;
>     }
>
>     return YES; }
>
>
> - (void)destroyFramebuffer {
>
>     glDeleteFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
>     viewFramebuffer = 0;
>     glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
>     viewRenderbuffer = 0;
>
>     if(depthRenderbuffer) {
>         glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
>         depthRenderbuffer = 0;
>     } }
>
>
> - (void)startAnimation {
>     self.animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:animationInterval target:self
> ```
>
> selector:@selector(mainGameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; }
>
> ```
> - (void)stopAnimation {
>     self.animationTimer = nil; }
>
>
> - (void)setAnimationTimer:(NSTimer *)newTimer {
>     [animationTimer invalidate];
>     animationTimer = newTimer; }
>
>
> - (void)setAnimationInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
>
>     animationInterval = interval;
>     if (animationTimer) {
>         [self stopAnimation];
>         [self startAnimation];
>     } }
>
>
>
> -(void) setupScore{
>
>     scoreLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
>     scoreLabel.frame = CGRectMake(262, 250, 100, 40);
>     [scoreLabel setText: scoreString];
>
>     //normally you'll want a transparent background for your label
>     scoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
>
>     //you can use non-standard fonts
>     [scoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRoman" size: 1.0f]];
>
>     //change the label's text color
>     scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
>
>     //add it to your view
>     scoreLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(89.53);
>     [self addSubview:scoreLabel]; }
>
> -(void) resetScore {
>     score = 0;
>     scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
>     [scoreLabel release]; }
>
> -(void)drawScore{  
>     [scoreLabel setText: scoreString]; }
>
> -(void) checkSquareToCircleCollisions{
>     NSMutableArray *array = [squares getSquares];
>
>     for(int i = 0; i < [squares getCount]; i++){
>
>         Square *s = [array objectAtIndex: i];
>
>         CGRect rect1 = [player getRect];
>         CGRect rect2 = [s getRect];
>
>         if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2)){
>
>             player.alive = NO;
>             gameState = 2;
>
>         }
>
>     } }
>
> -(void) checkSquareToSquareCollisions{
>     NSMutableArray *array = [squares getSquares];
>
>     for(int i = 0; i < [squares getCount]; i++){
>
>         Square *s = [array objectAtIndex: 0];
>         Square *ss = [array objectAtIndex: i];
>
>         CGRect rect1 = [s getRect];
>         CGRect rect2 = [ss getRect];
>
>         if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2)) {
>             [s setDirection: [s getXDir] * -1 : [s getYDir] * -1];
>             [ss setDirection: [ss getXDir] * -1 : [ss getYDir] * -1];
>         }
>
>     } }
>
> -(void) spawnSquares {
>     // FINISH METHOD
>      }
>
> -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
>
>     if(gameState == 0){
>
>         //MENU
>
>         UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
>
>         gameState = 1;
>         //[self initGame];
>
>     } else if(gameState == 1){
>
>         //GAMEPLAY
>
>         UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
>         CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
>         touchPos.y = 480 - touchPos.y;
>         [player setPos: touchPos];
>
>     } else if(gameState == 2){
>
>         //DEATH SCREEN
>
>         UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
>
>         gameState = 0;
>         //[self resetScore];
>         [self initGame];
>     } }
>
> -(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
>
>     if(gameState == 0){
>
>         //MENU
>
>         UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
>
>         //[self initGame];
>
>     } else if(gameState == 1){
>
>         //GAMEPLAY
>
>         UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
>         CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
>         touchPos.y = 480 - touchPos.y;
>         [player setPos: touchPos];
>
>     } else if(gameState == 2){
>
>         //DEATH SCREEN
>
>         UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
>
>     }}
>
> - (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer
>         didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
>
>     point.y = acceleration.y * 10;
>     point.x = acceleration.x * 10;
>
>     CGPoint pos = [player getPos];
>
>     pos = CGPointMake(pos.x + point.x, pos.y + point.y);
>     [player setPos: pos];
>
>     //Right - MAY HAVE TO CHANGE
>     if(pos.x < 0){
>         pos = CGPointMake(320, pos.y);
>     }
>
>     //left
>     if(pos.x < 320){
>         pos = CGPointMake(0, pos.y);
>     }
>
>     //Top
>     if(pos.y < 0){
>         pos = CGPointMake(pos.x, 460);
>     }
>
>     //Bottom
>     if(pos.x < 460){
>         pos = CGPointMake(pos.x, 0);
>     }
>      }
>
> - (void)dealloc {
>
>     [self stopAnimation];
>
>     if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == context) {
>         [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
>     }
>
>     [context release];  
>     [player release];
>     [menu release];
>     [sharedSoundManager release];
>     [bk release];
>     [squared release];
>     [squares release];
>     [scoreLabel release];
>     [scoreString release];
>
>     [super dealloc]; }
>
> @end // here it says: excepted } and also its excepting @end
> ```

Comment: Wow, that's an enormous amount of code! I hope you're aware of copying and pasting and did not manually re-type the entire code to the textbox!

Comment: Could you maybe trim down the code to only the relevant parts (the lines with errors)? That might make many more willing to answer the question, as I know many are turned away by the huge wall of code.

Comment: I agree, this is a massive code block.

Comment: @H2CO3, **---OFF** I hope he did manually.

Comment: @holex haha, true story!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a brace in the `runContinueCountdown` at the end of the second if statement.

```
if(timer <= 300){
            if(timer > 200){
                countdownNum = 3;
            }
```

Add a brace to the end of this `if` statement

Comment: Ohhhh ok. I didn't catch that. Thank You!